# Anybody knows how to do a binary search with a 2d array of strings?

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search

This is my array:

```
import numpy as np

Arr = np.array( [
    ["","A","B","C","D","E","F"],
    ["1","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["2","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["3","0","X","0","0","0","0"],
    ["4","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["5","0","0","0","X","0","0"],
    ["6","X","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["7","0","0","0","0","0","0"],
    ["8","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
])
```

I want to do a binary search but I don't know how to do it with an array of strings. Basically I want to look at the position in where all my "X" are.

```
def findRow(a, n, m, k):
#a is the 2d array
#n is the number of rows
#m is the number of columns
#k is the "X"
    l = 0
    r = n - 1
    mid = 0
    while (l <= r) :
        mid = int((l + r) / 2)
         
        # we'll check the left and
        # right most elements
        # of the row here itself
        # for efficiency
        if(k == a[mid][0]): #checking leftmost element
            print("Found at (" , mid , ",", "0)", sep = "")
            return
         
        if(k == a[mid][m - 1]): # checking rightmost element
            t = m - 1
            print("Found at (" , mid , ",", t , ")", sep = "")
            return
        if(k > a[mid][0] and k < a[mid][m - 1]):    # this means the element
                                                    # must be within this row
            binarySearch(a, n, m, k, mid)    # we'll apply binary
                                            # search on this row
            return
        if (k < a[mid][0]):
            r = mid - 1
        if (k > a[mid][m - 1]):
            l = mid + 1
 
def binarySearch(a, n, m, k, x):    #x is the row number
     
    # now we simply have to apply binary search as we
    # did in a 1-D array, for the elements in row
    # number
    # x
    l = 0
    r = m - 1
    mid = 0
    while (l <= r):
        mid = int((l + r) / 2)
         
        if (a[x][mid] == k):
            print("Found at (" , x , ",", mid , ")", sep = "")
            return
        if (a[x][mid] > k):
            r = mid - 1
        if (a[x][mid] < k):
            l = mid + 1
     
    print("Element not found")
```

This is what I have tried but this is for int 2d arrays. Now I have a string 2d Array and I'm trying to find the location of al my "X"'s.

I want to output to be: found in (A,6), (B,3), (D,5)

Comment: Presumably, you're searching for the value in the first element of each row, right?

Comment: The `bisect` module in Python will do binary search for you, you would just need to provide a `key` that selects the element you're looking for. https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html

Comment: Hum, based on your edit, your question has nothing to do with binary searching... Binary searching is for finding one element in a sorted array, not for counting things.

Comment: And how can I look for all the "X" position?

Comment: Please show what you have tried. It sounds like your question is trivial, and just needs a little bit of effort, maybe reading a Python tutorial. Give it a go on your own first, show us what you're tried, and when you get stuck ask a specific question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What output do you want to get here? I don't see how you'd use binary search, since like @joanis said, the array isn't sorted (except for the first element of each row, as well as the first element of each column). For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I want to look at the position in where all my "X" are.

You can use `np.where` to get the indices for each axis, then zip them to get index tuples for all the locations:

```py
>>> list(zip(*np.where(Arr == "X")))
[(3, 2), (5, 4), (6, 1)]
```

If you want the (row, column) "locations", you could do this:

```py
>>> [(Arr[row, 0], Arr[0, col]) for row, col in zip(*np.where(Arr == "X"))]
[('3', 'B'), ('5', 'D'), ('6', 'A')]
```

However, you seem to be treating an array as a table. You should consider using Pandas:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(Arr[1:, 1:], columns=Arr[0, 1:], index=range(1, len(Arr[1:]) + 1))

>>> df
   A  B  C  D  E  F
1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  X  0  0  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  0  X  0  0
6  X  0  0  0  0  0
7  0  0  0  0  0  0
8  0  0  0  0  0  0

>>> rows, cols = np.where(df == "X")

>>> [*zip(df.index[rows], df.columns[cols])]
[(3, 'B'), (5, 'D'), (6, 'A')]
```

Comment: Is there a way in which I can modidy the np.where output? 

I want the output to be: [(A,1),(B,1),....]

Comment: @Tuki107 see my edit